# How can I tell what javascript has been compiled when running V8

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

I have herd V8 compiles "hot code" optimise javascript performance. Is there any way I can tell what code has been compiled and what code has not?

Comment: Do you mean using devtools, or from the JS itself?

Comment: Check out http://mrale.ph/blog/2011/12/18/v8-optimization-checklist.html and http://mrale.ph/blog/2015/03/29/browser-as-an-interactive-disassembler.html

Comment: @Oriol. I don't mind what toolset.

Comment: @Bergi because I wish to get a better understanding of the code I'm writing and how it's being run by v8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost you will need to profile your code in the Profiles tab of the Javascript console in Chrome to see what is worth testing.  If a function, module, or whatever you are trying to test does not take up much time, it won't be worth your effort.

V8's JIT is going to make assumptions about your code, if those assumptions are true the code will be lightning fast.  If not V8 will deoptimize that code as your program continues.  Here is a for instance from my own tests.  In the code below I was testing a merge sort function I had written.

```
console.time('order');
msort(ob);
console.timeEnd('order');
```

The first run of 60000 random numbers completes after 8ms, and all of the following jump up to around 16ms.  Basically the JIT has issues with something I wrote so it recompiled my code.  I have seen the exact opposite occur where code jumps to twice as fast.  If you want to look at it, this is not the exact version, but one using es6 module syntax.
https://github.com/jamesrhaley/es2015-babel-gulp-jasmine/blob/master/src/js/mergeSort/mergeSort.js

Also if your code was not worth optimizing, then it won't be optimized to begin with.  Here is a couple of links that helped me improve my speed when writing js.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJPdhx5zTaw

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/#so-how-does-javascript-work-in-v8

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to build a standalone version of v8, you can just run the shell as follows: `d8 --trace-opt foo.js` (you might also want to deploy `--trace-deopt`, since your code might get deoptimized (and then reoptimized again..)).

Another useful option is `--print-code` which will let you see all the versions of machine code for all the functions which were compiled although this one is probably an overkill. Also there is `--print-opt-code`.

And lastly use `d8 --help` to see what other useful options v8 can take.